# performing sql operation in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, devise

I have `gem 'sqlite3'` installed in my rails application. **where** do i perform a query to check whether some records exist in the table.

In my rails console i ran `sqlite3`.

```
C:\Sites\iAuth>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from users;
Error: no such table: users
sqlite>
```

I have a table with users, but how come it says no such table exists. I am using `Devise` for `authentication`. Below is my model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: Where is your database stored?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes i did run my rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to refer to your db file directly:

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this command?

```
rails dbconsole
```

In this console you can run sql queries directly